# Updated gb4e + cgloss has fixed spacing between gloss and translation, but not between "preamble" and gloss

Tags: spacing, xetex, linguistics, gb4e, cgloss4e

I just changed the glossing in a paper I am writing in order to fix the alignment spacing, so instead of using /glll, I am using /gll + adding the top line manually with //. However, this has resulted in the weird extra spacing between this first line and the first line of the gloss. (But the spacing between the last line of the gloss and the translation line is still perfect.

Here is the code, though I am not sure

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex \label{label} \textit{ilázata}\\
\gll i- lázata \\
against- behind \\
\glt `behind' %\citation
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Here is a picture of the result:

[image: picture of problem]

EDIT: When I run a minimal example by itself, the spacing works perfectly. As such, I suppose the problem is likely something in my preamble? I've included this below:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
maxbibnames=99,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{CoenWritingSample.bib}

\title{Adpositions and Applicatives in Siouan: A Case Study of Lakhota-Dakota-Nakota, Catawba, and Crow}
\author{Noah Michael Coen\\[.4cm]{Supervisory Professor: Dr. Ryan Kasak}}
\date{November 26th, 2020}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{cgloss}
\noautomath

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[mcolblock,leipzighyper,toc]{leipzig}
\makeglossaries
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[main]

\begin{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your help! It is not an over-exaggeration to say this paper would never be this close to finished without all the help I've received from the stackexchange TeX community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}`. Apparently the `\gll` command triggers a new paragraph that is affected by the `setspace` package. A workaround is to surround your examples by the `singlespacing` environment provided by the package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss}

\begin{document}

\begin{singlespacing}
\begin{exe}
\ex \label{label} \textit{ilázata}\\
\gll i- lázata \\
against- behind \\
\glt `behind' %\citation
\end{exe}
\end{singlespacing}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so, so very much!